# Puppet: How to fix "Invalid resource type file_line"?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I have a freshly installed Puppet server with only one module configured and one managed client.

This is a MOTD module and looks like so:

```
class motd {
    file { "/etc/custom_motd.sh":
    path    => '/etc/custom_motd.sh',
    ensure  => present,
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "root",
    mode    => "775",
    content => template('motd/custom_motd.sh.erb'),
    #require => Class['nagios_client'],
    }

#    file_line { 'enable motd':
#    ensure  => present,
#    line    => '/etc/custom_motd.sh',
#    path    => '/etc/profile',
#    require  => File['/etc/custom_motd.sh']
#    }
}
```

When I run `puppet agent -t` on the client I get the proper result:

```
[root@pnd01 ~]# puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for pnd01.company.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1426413575'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Motd/File[/etc/custom_motd.sh]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.24 seconds
[root@pnd01 ~]#
```

But if I uncomment the "file line" section in the `init.pp` file of the module and then run `puppet agent -t` on the client, I get the following response:

```
[root@pnd01 ~]# puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type file_line at /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/motd/manifests/init.pp:17 on node pnd01.company.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
[root@pnd01 ~]#
```

Line 17 points to the "file_line" declaration.
I have the exact same module on another Puppet environment and it works there like a charm.
I've looked it up on Google and found a post which recommends to add:

```
pluginsync = true
```

to the `[main]` section of `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` on the client machine and I've done so but I still get the same error.

Any idea how to fix this issue or why does it even happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You likely need to install the [standard library](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib). On your other installation, this might have got pulled in by some other module you installed.

After that, use it with `include stdlib`.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add that I added it to the `init.pp` manifest of the module... is that the right place to add it?

Comment: Yes, that should be the place.

Comment: Can I add it in `/etc/puppet/environments/production/manifests/site.pp` instead?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error by the way.

Comment: Ok found it! also had to copy the stdlib folder to the modules directory of production. Thanks!

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, `include stdlib` is mostly superfluous. You only need it to get at the default *run stages* defined in this module. But don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Install stdlib using:

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-stdlib
```

Also include the below line at the top of your script.

```
include stdlib
```